# Adding items to list not behaivng as expected in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add list datatypes to a list in java. (prior background in python)

Only problem is my resultset is completely different that what I expect.

I am reading from a file which has the following content

````
```
Descent of Man
The Ascent of Man
The Old Man and The Sea
A Portrait of The Artist As a Young Man
    ```
````

My code is below:

````
    ```

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Input input = new Input();

        List<String> resultOfLists = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> allSentances = input.read();

        for (int i = 0; i < allSentances.size(); i++) {

            var sentance = allSentances.get(i);

            List<String> sentanceList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sentance.split(" ")));

            for (int v = 0; v < sentanceList.size(); v++) {

                String lastWord = sentanceList.get(sentanceList.size() - 1);

                int indexOfLastWord = sentanceList.size() - 1;

                sentanceList.remove(indexOfLastWord);

                sentanceList.add(0, lastWord);

                resultOfLists.add(sentanceList);

            }

        }

    }
    ```
````

I want the output to be added to resultOfLists in this format below:

````
```
[Man, Descent, of]
[of, Man, Descent]
[Descent, of, Man]
[Man, The, Ascent, of]
[of, Man, The, Ascent]
[Ascent, of, Man, The]
[The, Ascent, of, Man]
[Sea, The, Old, Man, and, The]
[The, Sea, The, Old, Man, and]
[and, The, Sea, The, Old, Man]
[Man, and, The, Sea, The, Old]
[Old, Man, and, The, Sea, The]
[The, Old, Man, and, The, Sea]
 ...... continued
```
````

But when I use

```
resultOfLists.addAll(sentanceList);
```

I get the following:

````
```
[Man, Descent, of]
[Man, Descent, of, of, Man, Descent]
[Man, Descent, of, of, Man, Descent, Descent, of, Man]
[Man, Descent, of, of, Man, Descent, Descent, of, Man, Man, The, Ascent, of]
[Man, Descent, of, of, Man, Descent, Descent, of, Man, Man, The, Ascent, of, of, Man, 
 The, Ascent]
```
````

When I just print sentanceList it looks correct. But when I try to add each sentanceList variable to a list it looks like the second output above.

Hope my question is understandable.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `List<List<String>>` and `add()` instead of `addAll()`.

Comment: Where would I declare this? 
List<List<String>>

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `LinkedList`, since the operation of removing from the end and adding to the front is much cheaper. You also need to create a new copy of your list each time you add it to the result list.

```
List<List<String>> resultOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> allSentances = Arrays.asList("Descent of Man", "The Ascent of Man");

for (String sentance : allSentances) {

  LinkedList<String> sentanceList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(sentance.split(" ")));

  for (int v = 0; v < sentanceList.size(); v++) {
    sentanceList.addFirst(sentanceList.removeLast());
    resultOfLists.add(new LinkedList<>(sentanceList));
  }
}

for(List<String> sentance : resultOfLists)
    System.out.println(sentance);
```

Output:

```
[Man, Descent, of]
[of, Man, Descent]
[Descent, of, Man]
[Man, The, Ascent, of]
[of, Man, The, Ascent]
[Ascent, of, Man, The]
[The, Ascent, of, Man]
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
resultOfLists.addAll(sentanceList)
```

you add all items of the *sentanceList* to the *resultOfList*. And therefore your *resultOfList* gets longer and longer.

*resultOfList* should be a List of Lists:

```
List<List<String>> resultOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

and you have to add the whole sentanceList as a List:

```
resultOfLists.add(sentanceList)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can spot many problems in your code:

1. **Editing the same reference:**

so you are in a loop mutating `sentanceList` `sentanceList.size()` times.
`resultOfLists.add(sentanceList);` does not store a clone of `sentanceList` in `resultOfLists` array.
it instead store a reference to `sentanceList` (Object of type list)

every:

```
List<String> sentanceList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sentance.split(" ")));
```

will create a new object. which you only created `allSentances.size()` times.

for starters, you can replace:

```
 resultOfLists.add(sentanceList);
```

with:

```
 resultOfLists.add(new ArryaList<String>(sentanceList));
```

2. **Overwriting the item at index 0**:

every:

```
sentanceList.add(0, lastWord);
```

will replace item a index 0 with `lastWord`.

what you essentially need to do is move all items to the right by one index and then place you item at index 0 by executing above statement.

3. **Perhaps, List is not the right data structure for what you are doing.**

consider using Queue.
you can initialize it by doing:

```
Queue outputQueue = new LinkedList();
```

and re-arranging you items using:

```
outputQueue.add(outputQueue.poll());
```

and then store every re-arranged version as:

```
 resultOfLists.add(new ArrayList(outputQueue));
```

Comment: I have so many questions unfortunately. Thank you so much for the response. I will respond when I have a better idea of what you are outlining.


First of all I need to know what a linked list is. 

Second I dont know what you mean by:

List<String> sentanceList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sentance.split(" ")));
will create a new object. which you only created allSentances.size() times.

creating a new obj here makes sense with each sentanceList I feel.

Comment: based on how many sentences you have and thus how many times you iterate, check the no. of times your execution uses `new` keyword. its only 4 times, i.e. the `no. of sentences you begin with` no of times. and in contrast to that you are expecting a larger no of arrangements of words